# Subcategory entry based on another column - SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, categories, check-constraints

I was wondering if it is possible in PostgreSQL to have a table that only accepts a column entry based on another column.

For example, if the category is 1 or 3, there are no sub categories so subcategory cannot be entered. However, if category is entered as 2, then subcategory can be entered as A or B as in the example below. When I tried this below, it will not allow entries for category 1 or 3. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

```
CREATE TABLE some_table (

category VARCHAR CHECK (category IN ('1','2','3'))

subcategory VARCHAR CHECK (subcategory IN ('A','B') AND category = '2')

)
```

Comment: If this is about `SQL-Server` then you could use computed columns https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/specify-computed-columns-in-a-table?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Just a small one: If `category` can only be one of three digits. I would define it

Comment: Since this is about postgresql then `GENERATED COLUMNS` should be your choice if this column will have value based on the entry on another column. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/ddl-generated-columns.html

Answer (score 1):

Your logic corresponds to this `check` constraint:

```
CHECK ( (category IN (1, 3) AND subcategory IS NULL) OR
        (category = 2 AND subcategory IN ( 'A', 'B' ) AND subscategory IS NOT NULL )
      )
```

You don't need a separate check on `category`.  This handles both the category and the subcategory.

Comment: This works well, thank you very much. The only change I made was to put subcategory IS NOT NULL at the end of the second statement to force the input to include a subcategory whenever category is 2. Very much appreciated!

Comment: @quite_cool . . . You are right.  `CHECK` constraints allow `NULL` values to pass the constraint.  So, an explicit `NULL` check is needed in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You need to extend the logic a little. The allowed cases are either `category` not being `'2'` and the `subcategory` being `NULL` or `category` being `'2'` and the `subcategory` is either `'A'` or `'B'`.

```
CREATE TABLE some_table
             (category varchar(1),
              subcategory varchar(1),
              CHECK (category IN ('1',
                                  '2',
                                  '3')),
              CHECK (category <> '2'
                     AND subcategory IS NULL
                      OR category = '2'
                         AND subcategory IN ('A',
                                             'B')));
```

Answer (score 0):

I would go:

```
CREATE TABLE some_table (
  category SMALLINT CHECK (category IN ( 1, 2, 3)) 
, subcategory CHAR(1) 
, CONSTRAINT c_some_table 
    CHECK (
         category IN (1,3)
      OR(category = 2 AND subcategory IN ( 'A', 'B') AND category = 2)
    )
);
```

A small integer is much quicker to compare than a string, and if category is a single character, then limit the length, a fixed-length CHAR is more efficient than a VARCHAR, at that length.

Comment: Thanks very much for your reply, this works well as well. Thanks for the input on the data types, still getting used to the various types and advantages of each.